# Getting string in side curly braces that also has more values in curly braces within it

Tags: java, regex, string

So here's my (java) string

```
String s = "Some string preceding this {\"Key1\": \"Val1\", \"Key2\": {\"embedKey1\": \"embedVal1\", \"embedKey2\": \"embedVal2\"}, \"Key3\" : \"Val3\", \"Key3\": \"Val4\"}, some value proceeding it"
```

I want to get everything that is within the outer curly braces. How do I do that? So far I've tried the following

```
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\{([^}]*)\\}");
    Matcher m = p.matcher(s);
    while(m.find()){
       System.out.println(m.group(1));
    }
```

This however, only prints

```
"Key1": "Val1", "Key2": {"embedKey1": "embedVal1", "embedKey2": "embedVal2"
```

Can someone please help me with this?

Comment: Don't use a regular expression. Use a JSON parser.

Comment: What about greedy matching: `Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(?s)\\{(.*)\\}");`?

Comment: Oh sweet, the greedy match worked. Is there a way to accept this answer? Also would be awesome if you can briefly explain what the regex is actually doing. Thanks @stribizhev

Comment: @DjShon:I posted the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get everything in between outer braces, or **between the first `{` and the last `}`**, use greedy matching with a `.` matching all symbols (with *DOTALL* mode):

```
String s = "Some string preceding this {\"Key1\": \"Val1\", \"Key2\": {\"embedKey1\": \"embedVal1\", \"embedKey2\": \"embedVal2\"}, \"Key3\" : \"Val3\", \"Key3\": \"Val4\"}, some value proceeding it";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(?s)\\{(.*)}");
Matcher m = p.matcher(s);
while(m.find()){
    System.out.println(m.group(1));
}
```

See [IDEONE demo](http://ideone.com/OsN92A)

The `(?s)` is an inline version of the `Pattern.DOTALL` modifier.

Answer (score 0):

For your particular example you can use a regex like this:

```
\{(.*?)\{.*?}(.*?)}
```

**[Working demo](https://regex101.com/r/qK5uI1/1)**

Match information

```
MATCH 1
1.  [40-64] `"Key1": "Val1", "Key2": `
2.  [116-149]   `, "Key3" : "Val3", "Key3": "Val4"`
```

On the other hand, if you want to even capture the inner curly braces you can use something easier like this:

```
\{(.*)}
```

**[Working demo](https://regex101.com/r/qK5uI1/2)**

Match information

```
MATCH 1
1.  [40-149]    `"Key1": "Val1", "Key2": {"embedKey1": "embedVal1", "embedKey2": "embedVal2"}, "Key3" : "Val3", "Key3": "Val4"`
QUICK REFERENCE
```

Remember to escape backslashes in java:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\{(.*)}");
Matcher m = p.matcher(s);
while(m.find()){
   System.out.println(m.group(1));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If It's just about outermost "{" and "}" as you mentioned in your problem, this may be one of the non-regex approach.

```
    int first=s.indexOf('{');
    int last=s.lastIndexOf('}');

    String result=s.substring(first, last+1);
```